# 1119: Access of possibly undefined property SPACE through a reference with static type Class

Tags: actionscript

Trying to get the space bar to do an action in ActionScript.

Here is bits of the code that are relative.

```
var space:Boolean = false;
```

.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.SPACE, kSpace);
```

.

```
function kSpace(e:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 40)
    {
        down = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38)
    {
        up = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 32)
    {
        shoot = true;
    }
}


function shootBullet()
{
    var bullet1:bullet = new bullet();
    bullet1.x = ship.x + ship.height / 2;
    bullet1.y = ship.y;
    bulletContainer.addChild(bullet1);
}
```

Getting the error Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 2, Line 17    1119: Access of possibly undefined property SPACE through a reference with static type Class.

Line 17 being `stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.SPACE, kSpace);`

Would love to get this sorted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyboardEvent.SPACE` is not an event. Try listening to either `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` or  `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP`

Comment: e.keyCode is the code for the key pressed at that moment so check for `e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE`. If you want to check if multiple keys are pressed at once you would have build your own construction to keep track of which buttons are down at a certain point because flash has no native functionality to check this.

Comment: Thank you very much Arno van Oordt!